# how to set a webform field value in my custom module

Tags: webforms

drupal 7 webform 7-3.18

My webform has a hidden field used to store an unique id. This id is generate from custom logic.

my code is to set this field value. 
'webform_client_form_1' is my webform id

```
function webform_custom_form_webform_client_form_1_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['submitted']['test_id']['#value'] = 'COURSE_ID-123456';      
}
```

When the form is submitted and view the submission result and this hidden field value is empty

Answer (score 2):

Ok, try not to confuse Webform module stuff with core drupal FAPI stuff.

You cannot set `$form['submitted']['test_id']['#value'] = 'COURSE_ID-123456';` in the form_alter because `$form` is not passed in by reference and the `submitted` key values is set after the form is `POST`ed to my knowledge.

So you're trying to put stuff into the form in the wrong time and place. If I was just using FAPI and not webform. I would not use a "hidden" form value (which isnt really *hidden* on the page), but use Form `build_args` or `$form_state['MYMODULE_temporary']` to hold my custom `course_id` in the FAPI form lifecycle so that the client never sees these values, but they are passed along through form validation and submission.

You can probably do the same technique I describe above and then implement hook_webform_submission_insert(), or hook_webform_submission_update() (if your form supports Drafts) to perform submission logic and look at your custom `course_id` stuff ...

Comment: Thankyou for directing me to webform api.
I just read the api why not using hook_webform_submission_presave() ?

I tried to dprint_r the $submission variable the see the data structure but nothing outputted.

Comment: I dont use _presave() ever because if you allow Drafts the form is saved many time(s); the 1st time is via an _insert() but the submission is still a Draft ... ultimate the 1st "final" save of a Draftable webform is on an hook_webform_submission_update() ... so depending on what you're actually doing, you need to figure out the correct API call that works with your desired logic.

Answer (score 0):

For my webform alterations I use a rules module, Rules Forms Support.  An example is that on form build I verify the user role and set a form element to hidden, so I have a field in the form only editable based on user role.  I know there is also a webform rules module, but I have found the Rules Forms Support module to be more robust and have greater application than just modifying webforms.  Rule actions can be used and even run or call the custom code to set the value at the proper step.